# VNC viewer shows black screen for one user and normal for the other

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, vnc

I installed TigerVNC on a CentOS 7 and configured its service for two users (user1 and user2). It worked perfectly until recently. When I try to connect with VNC Viewer with user1 it shows just a black screen, meanwhile with user2 everything is fine. Both ports for each of them are opened.

P.S. I have mainly used user1, I was working one some apache configurations and when I restarted the server it happened.

Thank you in advance.

`cat /etc/sysconfig/vncservers` showed this output:

```
THIS FILE HAS BEEN REPLACED BY /lib/systemd/system/vncserver@.service
```

Meanwhile `cat /lib/systemd/system/vncserver@.service` showed this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Remote desktop service (VNC)
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/vncserver -kill %i > /dev/null 2>&1 || :'
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/runuser -l <USER> -c "/usr/bin/vncserver %i"
PIDFile=/home/<USER>/.vnc/%H%i.pid
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/vncserver -kill %i > /dev/null 2>&1 || :'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting my own answer here in hope that it will help someone in the future.

So, I just closed the port from before, removed the previous `vncserver@:<port number>.service` , created a new vncserver service in another port but still coulnd't reload or restart the service.

After checking with sudo `tail /var/log/messages` I ended up deleting this folder `/tmp/.X11-unix/X4` , then restarted the service.

It finally works.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your vncservers service isn't configured properly.

Edit `/etc/sysconfig/vncservers` and make sure that your file looks like so:

```
VNCSERVERS="6:root 7:itai"
VNCSERVERARGS[6]="-geometry 1024x768"
VNCSERVERARGS[7]="-geometry 1152x864"
```

The first line configures which port each user will connect to... 6 translates to port 5906 and 7 translates to 5907.
The other lines configure the screen resolution for each user.

If you make any changes in the configure, don't forget to restart the service:

```
service vncservers restart
```

I hope that helps.